# How do I concatenate #define value?

Tags: c

I have following definitions

```
#define ID valve1

#define PROJECT "..\"+ID+"_data_var.h"
```

when I print `PROJECT` it should give below result

```
"..\valve1_data_var.h"
```

It means definition `PROJECT` should have   `"..\valve1_data_var.h"`

Comment: The question I have raised its related to embedded c

Answer (score 2):

You can generally use the `##` (double number sign) to concatenates two tokens in a macro invocation.

However, since you have string literals jamming an already defined macro, you could just use spaces, else you could run into invalid preprocessing token.

Also, you should escape your backslash.

```
#define ID "valve1"

#define PROJECT "..\\" ID "_data_var.h"
```

Comment: I got "..\\" valve1 "_data_var.h"  ... will compiler consider this as ..\valve1_data_var.h ?

Comment: #include  "..\\"##ID##"_data_var.h"  .. and also #include  "..\\" ID "_data_var.h" Its not working . I am getting below errors                                                                `#include' expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>... Here I have tried to include valve1_data_var.h file

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I would have thought about the `##` as well. It concatenates identifiers in order to form a larger one:

```
#define CONCATHELP(a,b,c) a##b##c
#define CONCAT3(a,b,c) CONCATHELP(a,b,c)
#define CONCAT2(a,b,c) CONCATHELP(a,,c)

#define STD(what) CONCAT2(std,what)
#define mysink err

...

fprintf(STD(mysink), ...) // prints to stderr
```

But in your case, you need [the stringifying `#` operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification) which turns a parameter into its argument's representation:

```
#define mkstr(s) #s

mkstr(foo) // is the same as "foo"
```

So in your case,

```
#define PROJX(id) "..\\" #id "_data_var.h"
#define PROJ(id) PROJX(id)
#define PROJECT PROJ(ID)
```

might be one way to go. Another alternative is

```
#define mkstrX(s) #s
#define mkstr(s) mkstrX(s)
#define PROJECT "..\\" mkstr(ID) "_data_var.h"
```

which does the same, getting a result of

```
"..\\" "valve1" "_data_var.h"
```

which, in turn, is understood by the compiler as the concatenation of the components.

The additional level of indirection is needed to help to become the `ID` mapping to `valve1` to become effective.

Comment: #define PROJECT "..\\" #ID "_data_var.h" Here why you used # before ID .. it has given  "..\\" #valve1 "_data_var.h" how the compiler will see this ?

Comment: @user3016320 Look how the data is propagated: from `PROJ(ID)` you get to `PROJX(valve1)`. As `id` is `valve1` then, `#id` becomes `"valve1"`.

Answer (score 0):

C preprocessor defines support token concatenation:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Basically, you use ## instead of +:

```
#define PROJECT "..\"##ID##"_data_var.h"
```

Comment: No its not working ... I got "possible real start of unterminated constant" error and its printed  "..\"##ID##"_data_var.h" instead of valve1_data_var.h

Answer (score 0):

```
#define PROJECT3(x) # x
#define PROJECT2(x) PROJECT3(x)
#define PROJECT "..\\" PROJECT2(ID) "_data_var.h"
```

It creates literal `"..\\" "valve1" "_data_var.h"` which compiler sees as a single string `"..\\valve1_data_var.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ID "valve1"

#define PROJECT(A,B,C) #A B #C
main()
{
       printf("%s\n", PROJECT(../,ID,_data_var.h));
       return;
}
```

Hope this helps